# Jersey JAX-RS ContainerResponseFilter sets response code to 200 regardless of ResponseBuilder.status

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I've written a class that implements ContainerRequestFilter and ContainerResponseFilter. In the request filter, there is an authentication check, and if it fails, it builds a 401 response using ResponseBuilder.

When I inspect the HTTP response code from the client side (I've tested with a browser debugger and SoapUI), its 200 instead of 401. But the response body is the content I set. My debug logs and the Jersey response LoggerFeature both report that the status code is 401. Its confounding.

The logs:

```
[2021-07-14 15:57:45.974][TRACE][] - [Entering filter response]
[2021-07-14 15:57:45.975][TRACE][] - [Response context org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse@62e8911f]
[2021-07-14 15:57:45.976][TRACE][] - [Response status info 401 Unauthorized]
[2021-07-14 15:57:45.977][DEBUG][o.g.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature] - [4 * Server
 responded with a response on thread http-nio-8180-exec-7
4 < 401
4 < Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform
4 < Content-Encoding: ISO-8859-1
]
```

The ResponseBuilder code:

```
ResponseBuilder rb = Response
    .status(Statuses.from(response.getStatus(), "TheStatus"))
    .entity(response.getBodyContent())
    .encoding(response.getCharacterEncoding())
    .cacheControl(CC);

for (Cookie c : response.getCookies())
    rb = rb.cookie(CookieConverter.toJaxRsNewCookie(c));

OutboundJaxrsResponse actualResponse = (OutboundJaxrsResponse) rb.build();
logger.trace("Actual response {}", actualResponse);
logger.trace("Status {}", actualResponse.getStatus());
logger.trace("Context {}", requestContext);
logger.trace("ResponseBuilder {}", rb);
requestContext.abortWith(actualResponse);
```

And here's what SoapUI (and browser/debugger) shows it receives:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Set-Cookie: GWCHALLENGE=YES; Domain=.sand.idfconnect.lan; Path=/; HttpOnly
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="rm-gw"
Content-Length: 190
Date: Wed, 14 Jul 2021 19:57:45 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
Connection: keep-alive

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>401: Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<h1>401: Access Denied</h1>
<br>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I must be missing something... I've tried Jersey 2.29 through 2.33, same difference.

Any help GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: I would need to see a complete example to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause was that the particular service behind the filter was writing the HTML for the response body before setting the status code, which is wrong. Once something is written to the response body, the status code cannot be changed.